# Proving that if $H$ is not normal, then $HgH$ is not a left coset for some $g \in G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups

I'm having trouble proving that if $H$ is a non-normal subgroup of a group $G$, then there exists $g \in G$ such that $HgH$ is not a left coset. Here is my attempt, some steps of which I'm not totally sure of (and which I've bolded).

> We proceed by contraposition. Suppose that for every $g \in G$, the double coset $HgH$ is a left coset; we will prove that $H$ is normal. Fix $g \in G$. **I claim that $HgH = gH$. Indeed, if $x \in gH$, then $x = gh$ for some $h \in H$, hence $x = ghe \in HgH$ since $H$ is a subgroup and therefore contains the identity. Therefore, we have $HgH \supset gH$. As $HgH$ must equal some left coset, and the left cosets partition $G$ into equivalence classes, which are either equal or disjoint, we must have $HgH = gH$**.
>
> We will show that $H$ is normal, i.e., that $Hg = gH$. If $x \in Hg$, then $x = hge$ for some $h \in H$, hence $x \in HgH$, hence $x \in gH$, so $Hg \subset gH$. Multiplying by $g^{-1}$ on the left, we find that $g^{-1} Hg \subset H$. Conversely, multiplying by $g$ on the left and $H$ on the right gives $H \subset gHg^{-1}$. **As this holds for all $g \in G$, it holds upon replacing $g$ with $g^{-1}$, hence $H \subset g^{-1} H g$**, so $H = g^{-1} H g$, hence $gH = Hg$, so $H$ is normal.

I'd appreciate some help with the bolded parts of my attempted proof above. I'm especially not certain on the argument for why $HgH = gH$, but I couldn't figure out how to prove directly that $H g H \subset gH$.

Comment: I see many typos, can you fixed them?

Comment: Since this is a [tag:solution-verification] question, [this is not a duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1929440/104041), but it has a proof of the theorem in question.

Comment: Is $G$ finite  ?

Comment: @MathFail Yes I'll fix them. Sorry about that. As for the second question: I'm trying to proceed by contraposition, so the claim would be that if $HgH$ is a left coset for every $g \in G$, then $H$ is normal.

Comment: @Mike I believe I want to allow $G$ to be infinite as well here.

Comment: @Shaun Thank you, I appreciate the link.

Comment: Your proof is entirely correct, including the bolded parts and even for $G$ infinite.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you very much. Is there another way to see that $HgH = gH$? Or is it enough to say that that $HgH = aH$ for some $a \in G$, and since the intersection of two cosets is either trivial or the entirety, we must have $a = g$?

Comment: Your way was perfect. We must not have $a=g$ but $aH=gH.$

Comment: I add a complete proof. @BradG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your bolded part:

Since $HgH$ is some left coset of $H$, let $HgH=aH$, you have shown $gH\subseteq HgH=aH$, hence
$$\exists x, ~ x\in gH\land x\in aH\Longrightarrow \exists h_1,h_2\in H,~~ gh_1=x=ah_2$$

then we have

$$a=gh_1h_2^{-1}=gh_3,~~~h_3=h_1h_2^{-1}\in H$$

hence

$$HgH=aH=(gh_3)H=g(h_3H)=gH$$

---

Next, a quicker way to show $H$ is normal,

$$\forall g\in G, \forall h\in H,~~ \color{red}{g^{-1}hg}=g^{-1}hge \color{red}\in g^{-1}HgH=\color{red}H$$